# VBA String Concatenation not working as expected

Tags: vba

Im trying to use concatenation to make a connection string.
Heres the code:

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=MyCat;Data Source=" & serverName & ";User ID=MyId;Password=MyPwd;"
```

serverName is a string defined like this: serverName = "ServerName\InstaceName"

I am expecting for objMyConn.Connection string to be = to the whole connection staring however it is = to this:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=MyCat;Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName
```

So I'm missing the last part of my connection string.

Comment: Can you try `serverName = "ServerName\\InstanceName"` ?

Comment: The \ char needing to be escaped was my first thought also. however this did not solve the problem.

Comment: What happens if you set serverName = "fred"? Do you still lose the last part of the conn string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADODB Connection.ConnectionString property doesn't return server name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940720/adodb-connection-connectionstring-property-doesnt-return-server-name)

Comment: According to [MSDN: ADO Connection String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821690.aspx), you should use single quote mark `'` in your connection string, so `objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider='SQLOLEDB';Initial Catalog='MyCat';Data Source='" & serverName & "';User ID='MyId';Password='MyPwd';"`

Comment: @DeanOC yes I still lose the rest of the connection string if I change the server name

Comment: @MincongHuang Thanks, but this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this, Just in case anyone else has the same problem.

When declaring my variable server name I had given it a length of 255, I changed the length to the appropriate length needed.